# Getting "Terminated due to timeout" in hackerRank for below prog

Tags: java, deque

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Deque deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int m = in.nextInt();
            int maxUnique =0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int num = in.nextInt();
                if(i ==0)
                {
                    deque.add(num);
                    maxUnique++;
                }
               else{
                   if(deque.size() == m)
                   {
                       deque.removeFirst();
                   }
                   if (!deque.contains(num) && maxUnique<m)
                   {
                       maxUnique++;
                   }
                   deque.addLast(num);
               }
            }
            System.out.println(""+maxUnique);
        }
    }
```

I am expecting some alternate option to optimize it further or need to know what am i doing wrong here ..in eclipse it gets passed

Comment: Did you try taking all the input at once instead of doing it per step in your for loop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> deque.contains(num)
> ```

This will have to scan the entire deque. If there are a few million items in there, that's going to take a while. The technical term for this is that "it has `O(n)` performance", which means: If you make a graph with on the x-axis: How large the input is (`n`) - here, how many numbers you read), and on the y-axis you would graph how long your program takes, that, eventually (with a large enough n), it looks like the curve `y=x`.

You're looking instead for an algorithm that is `O(log n)` (i.e. where the performance eventually looks like `y= log x`, which is a line that turns essentially horizontal, i.e. doesn't become any slower as input grows), or even `O(1), meaning, it looks like` y=1`, i.e. a flat line - it takes X seconds, no matter if the input is 10 elements or 100 million elements.

Specifically, for each number, you do something, so that part is `O(n)`, and then 'the thing you do' is itself `O(n)`, so that's `O(n)*O(n)` which is `O(n^2)` - which is too slow.

You can't avoids having to read all input, so that `O(n)` must stay. Which means the `O(n)` introduced by `deque.contains(num)` has to go.

A trivial way to do is, is to use HashSets; assuming good hash distribution their `add`, `remove`, and `contains` operations are all `O(1)`.

Knowledge of how long things take (in terms of `O(n)` - this is called 'big O notation') is **required knowledge** when doing such puzzles. There are plenty of tutorials out there, but it's complicated, and requires real study. Failure to know this stuff means you're just going to run headfirst into 'terminated due to timeout' errors every time.